# Not able to take screenshot for a specific element in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I want to take the snapshot of an element using protractor and protractor supports the element.takeScreeshot(). However when i am using it throws the Some session error(below)

```
 element(by.model('model.username')).takeScreenshot().then(ab=>{

)}
```

**Error**

```
**- Failed: GET /session/5d58e1ca-f55d-4b51-aee8-1d518498cb35/element/0/screenshot
  Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
  System info: host: 'INBEN10174', ip: '157.237.220.180', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown**
```

Comment: Check the browser driver versions and compare at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.takeScreenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can screenshot the entire page and then crop the image to the element you want:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

var elem = element(by.model('model.username'));

promise.all([
    elem.getLocation(),
    elem.getSize(),
    browser.takeScreenshot()
]).then(function(result) {
    var src = PNG.sync.read(Buffer.from(result[2], 'base64'));
    var dst = new PNG({width: result[1].width, height: result[1].height});
    PNG.bitblt(src, dst, result[0].x, result[0].y, dst.width, dst.height, 0, 0);
    fs.writeFileSync('out.png', PNG.sync.write(dst));
});
```

This will output a .png image of the selected element.
As mentioned below, you will need to make sure the element is on the screen prior to this; which is achievable like so:

```
var elem = element(by.model('model.username'));
browser.actions().mouseMove(elem).perform();
```

Comment: 1 addition to your solution is that each webdriver takes a different screenshot. So determining the location this way will not work on for example Firefox < 48 or IE 11 because they take screenshots of the complete full page instead of the viewport. A module, as mentioned in my answer, can solve this problem. Also it solves the problem for mobile

Answer (score 1):

As said by @suresh-salloju, it's a new feature and even on my chromedriver 2.30 and selenium 3.4.0 is throws the same answer.

If you want to be able to take a screenshot of an element you can maybe use [protractor-image-comparison](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison). The methods `saveElement` or `checkElement` can help with testing. Only be sure that you scroll the element in the viewport.